# Excel - How to change a shape color based of the color of another cell

Tags: excel, vba, colors, shapes, excel-2016

I am trying to change the color of multiple shapes based off a table on another tab. The table contains part, quadrant, shape name, and value (cell with specific color.) I am trying to tie the shape to the color by using shape name and range of where the color cell is but I get a sub/function not defined. The colors for the values in the table is based off a conditional format.

```
Sub Update()

Dim CellColor As Long
Dim ShapeColor As Variant

    CellColor = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    ShapeColor = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
    Worksheets("main").Shapes(ShapeColor).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = CellColor

    Worksheets("main").Select
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Set` should not be used here. `Worksheet("main")` is missing an `s` - `Worksheets`.

Comment: If conditional formatting, then you need to work with `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comments to an answer:

- `Set` should not be used here. `Worksheet("main")` is missing an s - `Worksheets`.
- If conditional formatting, then you need to work with `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`.

Comment: I updated the code that works, how would I go about having this code ran for each row in the table? I have 100 rows that need this code ran for it.

Comment: @bullfrog97 - you would need a loop. `For Each cell in Range("C2:C100")` or whatever. Then `cell.Offset(,1)` will refer to the cell in column D. Give it a shot and feel free to post a new question if you can't get it to work.